# R Script Cannot Read File

Tags: r

I have an R script that reads a set of files in a directory. When running it, I run into the error below even though when I read the filename interactively (in the console), it works:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument
```

This is the code that reads the file:

```
 for(i in 1:length(id_vector)){

     # Pad filename with 0s
     padded_id <- formatC(i, width = 3, format = "d", flag = "0"); 

     location <- paste(getwd(),'/',directory,'/',padded_id,".csv",sep="");

     # Read input file
     data <- read.csv(location);
 }
```

Comment: No need for loop, try something like this `MyCSVfiles <- lapply(list.files(),read.csv)`

Comment: @zx8754 which is the recommended way, but still a loop.

Comment: @Roland agreed, I meant all the additional code required by use of "for loop". Should have said "No need for `for` loop" :)

Comment: `data <- read.csv(location)` part will overwrite previous data and will have only the last file in it.

Comment: It's ok for the data to be overwritten. There's still code after that for processing the contents.

Comment: One other information I just discovered. When I read the file outside the loop, the script is able to access the file. read.csv("directory/001.csv"); .

Answer (score 0):

In place of paste try file.path()

file.path(getwd(),directory,paste(padded_id,".csv", sep=""))

Comment: It still doesn't work. I printed the directory that was produced and did a read.csv on the console using the directory and it works. However, in the script the same error popped up.

Comment: You say you've tried printing the directory. Have you tried printing the value of 'location'? What about file.exists(location) or file.info(location) or file.access(location).